# Prove that the radical of an ideal is an ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. For an ideal $I$ of $R$, I am attempting to prove $\sqrt{I}=\{x\,|\,x^n\in I\}$ is an ideal.

Closure under multiplication with $R$ seems straight forward: for $x\in\sqrt{I}$ and $r\in R$, $(rx)^n=r^nx^n\in I,$ so $rx\in\sqrt{I}.$

My question relates to proving closure under addition.  What I have currently is that if $x^n, y^m\in I$ and assuming $m\leq n$, then $x^n\left(x^n+2nx^{n-1}y+\dotsb+\binom{2n}{n}y^n\right)+y^m\left(\binom{2n}{n+1}x^{n-1}y^{(n-m)+1}+\dotsb+y^{2n-m}\right)=(x+y)^{2n},$ implying that $(x+y)\in\sqrt{I}$.

It seems like even if I am correct there is probably a more straight-forward way of doing this. I searched this site and found and answer that I don't understand, so I'm worried I might be missing something.

Comment: That's the proof I know, but also you're missing the coefficients in the binomial expansion. Also $n+m$ works as an exponent.

Comment: In fact $n+m-1$ works.

Comment: I understand now.  I didn't get why binomial expansion worked, but I didn't do anything any differently... except forget the coefficients. Thanks @jgon

Answer (score 3):

You can use the nilradical, which is the set of all nilpotent elements of R.

Notice that if I is the ideal of the ring R and r(I) is the radical of I and $x^n$ is in I, then $x^n + I = I$ so $(x + I)^n = I$. Thus $r(I) = f^{-1}(N(R\setminus I))$ where $N(R\setminus I)$ is the nilradical of $R\setminus I$ and f is the function from R to $R\setminus I$ defined by $f(x)=x + I$.